# Wordpress HTTP requests point to localhost server after move to live HTTPS server

Tags: https

After moving a site, some requests still point towards my local wamp server; http://localhost/

A couple of fonts and maybe one or two images have this issue. I've changed the site URL and the changes are visible in the database options table.

I can't seem to find the exact location of the request that causes the issue. Is there a way to change where all requests point to?

Thanks in advance!

Best regards,

Lex

Answer (score 2):

If you developing wordpress on localhost, you have to do 2 important things when you want to make it live:

1- search and replace in your .sql backup file for **localhost/wordpress** and replace it with new address and then import it in your live server.

2- search and replace your whole code, if you use hard-coded addresses!

for more information visit this [link](https://torquemag.io/2016/02/move-wordpress-from-localhost-to-live-server/)

Comment: Make sure that the find and replace tool supports replacing strings in serialized arrays, since absolute URLs are often stored in the DB this way. I typically use [WP Migrate DB](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/) for this.

Comment: aslo NotePad++ is good too!